# Why links to my website fails to open in facebook app?

Tags: facebook, ios

When users try to open posts of my website shared on Facebook on their mobile device it shows the error
[image: Can't connect Sorry something went wrong]

> Can't connect
>
> Sorry something went wrong

This seems to be quite common for iOS devices. I have not received any report of this on android nor was I able to produce it myself on android.

It should be noted that the website does not seem to show any relevant issue when accessing through a browser. Initially I assumed it is a network issue, but links to no other site seem to show the same issue.

What are the possible reasons for this error and what should be my steps to investigate it?

Comment: I am totally guessing this, but I would first think about your website security and see if any problems are flagged here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Nothing there, the report comes with grade A. Also, the error mentioned does not appear all the time. It fails around 5% of the times on iOS. And it would load fine if retried.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to be able to answer this definitively so users can only guess. [Troubleshooting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) individual websites is considered off-topic here because it takes too much back-and-forth to determine what the problem might be, which doesn't fit the format of this single Q & A website. I'd suggest looking at your server's error logs to see what the issue could be.

Comment: @dan My server error logs doesn't have anything regarding this. In fact, the requests seem to succeed even for the requests facebook shows the error for. And since it doesn't happen when accessing the site in any other means, I am almost certain that the issue is not on the website's end but something with the facebook app. This is why I am looking for possible approaches to fix this issue.

Comment: Questions here are unfortunately required to be about a [website under your own control](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Since as you say this appears to be a bug regarding Facebook's app, I'd suggest reporting it to them [here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/) or seeking help from their developer's community.